# How to retrieve month wise data using SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Table `Account` has columns `Id` (int), `Category_Id` (int), `OpeningDate` (Datetime), `ClosingDate` (Datetime) and `Status` (boolean).

- Status = 1 means Active
- Status = 0 means Inactive

`ClosingDate` is `NULL` for active accounts.

I need a monthwise active Account.

Output should be:

```
Year Month     Category_Id  Accounts
------------------------------------
2019 January       1         45
2019 January       2         30
2019 February      1          5
2019 February      2         10
```

So far, I am using this SQL statement:

```
Select 
    Count(Id),
    Category_Id
from 
    Account 
where 
    Status = 1 
Group By 
    Category_Id
```

Comment: What do you mean by "monthwise active account"?

Comment: Suppose, for January 2019, I need only those accounts which are active in that month

Answer (score 1):

Use date functions and aggregation:

```
Select year(openingdate), datename(month, openingdate),
       category_id, count(*)
from Account 
where Status = 1 
Group By year(openingdate), datename(month, openingdate),
         category_id
order by min(openingdate), category_id;
```

EDIT:

I suspect that you mean actives during the month, based on the opening and closing date -- not just on the status.  A reasonable interpretation is actives on the first of the month:

```
select d.yyyymm, c.category_id,
       count(a.id)
from (values (convert(date, '2019-01-01')),
             (convert(date, '2019-02-01'))
     ) d(yyyymm) cross join
     (values (1), (2)
     ) c(category_id) left join
     account a
     on a.category_id = c.category_id and
        a.openingdate <= d.yyyymm and
        (a.closingdate > d.yyyymm or a.closingdate is null)
group by d.yyyymm, c.category_id
order by d.yyyymm, c.category_id;
```

Comment: Its working! but, I want to get for any date range given as input. Suppose, Input StartDate is '1-2-2019' and EndDate is '31-12-2019'.

Comment: @BlackCat . . . Probably the simplest way is to just expand the date range in the `values()` clause.  You an also use a recursive CTE to generate the dates, a number table, a calendar table, or extract them from your table.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server provide Date functions that allow you to handle date and time data effectively. For more information, see [here](http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-date-functions/).

> [image]